# Proving properties of an ellipse

Tags: calculus, geometry, conic-sections

I'm studying about ellipse and its properties. My reference is the following pdf:

http://nebula.deanza.edu/~bloom/math43/ellipse-derivation.pdf

My questions are from the very first page of the pdf-file (questions in image below):

[image]

Could someone give me analytical proofs? :)

Thnx for any help =)

Comment: There are various **definitions** of an ellipse. One of them is that an ellipse is the locus of points $P$ such that the sum of the distances from $P$ to two given not necessarily distinct points $A$ and $B$ is constant. That is the definition the author is using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that is the definition of an ellipse. The following calculation will tell you this.

$$\sqrt{(x-(-c))^2+(y-0)^2}+\sqrt{(x-c)^2+(y-0)^2}=A$$
$$\Rightarrow \sqrt{(x+c)^2+y^2}=A-\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2}$$
$$\Rightarrow (x+c)^2+y^2=A^2-2\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2}+(x-c)^2+y^2$$
$$\Rightarrow 2\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2}=A^2+(x-c)^2+y^2-(x+c)^2-y^2$$
$$\Rightarrow 4(x-c)^2+4y^2=(A^2-4cx)^2$$
$$\Rightarrow (1-4c^2)x^2+2c(A^2-1)x+y^2=\frac{A^2}{4}-c^2.$$